# How to submit a form in scrapy?

Tags: python, forms, web-scraping, scrapy

I tried to use scrapy to complete the login and collect my project commit count. And here is the code.

```
from scrapy.item import Item, Field
from scrapy.http import FormRequest
from scrapy.spider import Spider
from scrapy.utils.response import open_in_browser


class GitSpider(Spider):
    name = "github"
    allowed_domains = ["github.com"]
    start_urls = ["https://www.github.com/login"]

    def parse(self, response):
        formdata = {'login': 'username',
                'password': 'password' }
        yield FormRequest.from_response(response,
                                        formdata=formdata,
                                        clickdata={'name': 'commit'},
                                        callback=self.parse1)

    def parse1(self, response):
        open_in_browser(response)
```

After running the code

```
scrapy runspider github.py
```

It should show me the result page of the form, which should be a failed login in the same page as the username and password is fake. However it shows me the [search page](https://github.com/search). The log file is located in [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/0gRaNm7D)

How should the code be fixed? Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you mind sharing the log results ? Trying your code I noticed a Crawled (301) <GET https://www.github.com/login>

Comment: http://pastebin.com/0gRaNm7D Thanks

Comment: not solved by this direct approach. what about using webdriver ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your problem is that `FormRequest.from_response()` uses a different form - a "search form". But, you wanted it to use a "log in form" instead. Provide a `formnumber` argument:

```
yield FormRequest.from_response(response,
                                formnumber=1,
                                formdata=formdata,
                                clickdata={'name': 'commit'},
                                callback=self.parse1)
```

Here is what I see opened in the browser after applying the change (used "fake" user):

[image]

Comment: Thanks that works. I checked the official document and have no idea how that formnumber works. Here is the link http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.FormRequest

Comment: @Winston it is quite simple actually. The page contains multiple forms: the first one (with index `0` and the one used by default) is the search form; the second one - is the login form (with index `1`). `formnumber` lets Scrapy know that we are interested in the form number `1`. Hope that clears things up.

Answer (score 5):

Solution using webdriver.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import time
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider

class GitSpider(CrawlSpider):

    name = "gitscrape"
    allowed_domains = ["github.com"]
    start_urls = ["https://www.github.com/login"]

    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()

    def parse(self, response):
        self.driver.get(response.url)
        login_form = self.driver.find_element_by_name('login')
        password_form = self.driver.find_element_by_name('password')
        commit = self.driver.find_element_by_name('commit')
        login_form.send_keys("yourlogin")
        password_form.send_keys("yourpassword")
        actions = ActionChains(self.driver)
        actions.click(commit)
        actions.perform()
        # by this point you are logged to github and have access 
        #to all data in the main menù
        time.sleep(3)
        self.driver.close()
```

Comment: Thanks your code works. But just wonder why scrapy is not working in this example. I tried to fill the form in delta.com web site and it works.

Comment: "Working solution for Scrapy" - are you sure you can successfully log in with the code you provided?

Comment: the response url print the correct and it open the github page with the correct user. Do you have a different result ?

Comment: @aberna yup, I see the following url being printed after running your code: `https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=&login=yourlogin&password=your+password` - see it uses a search form - check out my answer. Thanks.

Comment: @alexce You are right the solution for scrapy was not complete. Your code is more appropriate

Answer (score 2):

Using the "formname" argument also works:

```
yield FormRequest.from_response(response,
                            formname='Login',
                            formdata=formdata,
                            clickdata={'name': 'commit'},
                            callback=self.parse1)
```